How does Numpy normalize eigenvectors?
I'm trying to understand how numpy normalizes the eigenvectors from the command np.linalg.eig(), as it doesn't seem to be using a scalar factor to normalize them. For example, it normalized the eigenvector [3,0,-1] to [0.194078, -0.955099, -0.223876], which doesn't make sense to me, as the middle number would remain a zero if normalized in a usual way. So, can someone explain the process numpy uses to compute and normalize the eigenvalues? I'm trying to understand the process to see if it's reversible.
I've tried standard scalar normalization and standard unit normalization, but those did not produce the same results.
Code:
import numpy as np
import scipy
from numpy.linalg import eig

a1=np.array([[4,-1,6],[2,1,6],[2,-1,8]])
w, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(a1)
trueeigens = np.array([[1,1,1],[-3,0,1],[1,2,0]])

trueeigens is the true eigenvectors when calculated by hand, eigenvectors is the eigenvectors given by Numpy, unsure why there is a difference

That matrix has an eigenvalue of multiplicity 2. The corresponding eigenspace has dimension 2. You're not guaranteed to see a scalar multiple of any particular element of that eigenspace in the output.

@user2357112 ok, but how about the matrix [[1,2,4],[0,4,7],[0,0,6]]? This matrix does not have a multiplicity eigenvalue, and while the first eigenvector is trivial, the second and third eigenvalue are also not scalar multiples of the correct values.

@ChefB: What output were you expecting for that input? The output looks fine to me.

@user2357112 some scalar multiple of [0.33333, 1, 0]

@ChefB: That's not an eigenvector of that matrix. Multiplying that matrix by [1/3, 1, 0] produces [7/3, 4, 0].

@user2357112, sorry, I made two errors there. It should have been [0.666666, 1, 0], but that is a scalar multiple. So why doesn't it work when the multiplicity of the eigenvalues is two?

@ChefB: Okay, consider a more extreme example. Suppose you instead had the 3x3 identity matrix, which has an eigenvalue of 1 with multiplicity 3. [25, -7, 6] is an eigenvector of this matrix, as is literally every other vector you could possibly multiply by this matrix (except the zero vector, because the definition of "eigenvector" excludes that). Would you expect a multiple of [25, -7, 6] in the output? You wouldn't, right?

@user2357112 That kinda makes sense. But what about a case where there's a zero in the eigenvector? Why does the numpy eigenvector fill in that value? Shouldn't it remain a zero? The main part of my question is what is numpy doing to get the specific values it returns, even when there is a multiplicity?

The multiples of any particular eigenvector form a line, but an eigenspace of dimension N isn't just N lines put together. For dimension 2, it's a plane. For higher dimensions, it's a hyperplane. The eigenvector you're interested in might be in that plane, but NumPy doesn't have to pick a vector that points in that direction. There are many other directions to pick.

@user2357112 so there'd be no way to retrieve the specific eigenvalue I'm looking for? There's no formula to resolve a specific solution?

If you already know what you're looking for, you don't need NumPy to tell you.

@user2357112 true, but I'm trying to use NumPy to compute the eigenvectors, not doing it by hand or with an online calculator

@ChefB: But then there isn't a specific output you're looking for, is there?

@user2357112 I mean, I'm somewhat looking for a specific output. [0.66666, 1, 0] and [0.5547002, 0.8320502, 0] may be equivalent, but one is a lot more "understandable" than the other. I guess I'm saying the one I'd be looking for is one made of integers, so I'd change [0.666666, 1, 0] to [2, 3, 0].

I don't know of a good way to get that, then.

@user2357112 Gotcha. Well, thanks for your help anyway!

Are you always looking for all all-integer eigenvectors of all-integer matrices, or is it more like the more integers the better, but not guaranteed to be possible?

@Ry- the starter matrix where I'll be getting the eigenvectors from will always be integers, and always be real and not complex. I do want the eigenvectors to be all integers too, but if one of the components came out to be 2.25 or something like that, I can scale it up until they're all integers.

I did the eigenvectors using sympy and R and get different results from the one in numpy. Probably an issue with numpy

@Onyambu I have done the calculation with sympy, and it does indeed print the results I'm expecting. However, part of what I'm wanting to do is to create code that undoes what numpy is doing and create "regular" eigenvalues using numpy. I'm trying to create a function that inputs a matrix and outputs the eigenvalues and eigenvalues, with the eigenvalues being "regular".

(Remember to mind the XY problem.) If SymPy works, why do you need it for numpy? Performance? (This is relevant to an answer I was thinking of giving, for example.)

First the eigen values spitted by sympy are exactly equal to normalized eigen values spitted by R. R and numpy do not agree.  Note that for correct eigen vectors you can do QEQ^{-1} and determine as to whether the Q matrix is correct. Using numpy, I am unable to recreate the original matrix, meaning the eigen vectors spewed out are incorrect.

@Onyambu: Show the NumPy code you’re trying for that?

@Onyambu eigenvectors@np.diag(w)@np.linalg.inv(eigenvectors) reproduces the original matrix.

@jared I dont know what I did at first. You are right, it does reproduce the matrix. Although am still amused as to how numpy's eigen vectors do not match R's/ Mathematica/sympy/wolfram alpha. I havent checked on matlab though. Wondering why numpy would give different results --not refering to the multiplicity factor

@Ry- I need to use numpy because I'm trying to understand the behavior of numpy and how it calculates the eigenvectors. Using sympy would give me the correct answer, but wouldn't actually solve the problem I'm trying to work on.

@jared that code definitely produces the eigenvector matrix, but doesn't seem to work when there is multiplicity. Does this mean that numpy's eigenvectors are incorrect, or is something else going on?

@ChefB Can you give an example of when it doesn't work?

Numpy normalizes eigenvectors to have a Euclidean (L2) norm of 1, not necessarily using a scalar for each component of the eigenvector. The normalization is applied to the whole vector, not each individual component.
For example, for an eigenvector ( v ), Numpy scales it such that ( |v|_2 = 1 ), where ( |v|_2 ) is the Euclidean norm of ( v ).
If the original vector is ( [x, y, z] ), after normalization it will be:
[ \left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}, \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}\right] ]
So, even if one of the components was zero, like in your example ( [0, -1, 0] ), it remains zero after normalization since dividing by the norm does not affect zero elements. The non-zero elements are scaled appropriately.
The specific process that Numpy uses is part of its numerical algorithms based on LAPACK routines, which ensure numerical stability and efficiency. The result is that the eigenvectors are normalized in a way that their magnitude is 1, which is a common practice for numerical computation of eigenvectors.

Is this AI-generated?
